# Console output into html file every X seconds

Tags: node.js

I have this code in which results get printed in console, and I want to output them into a .html file:

```
if (result.items.length > 0 && result.items[0].userName === player) {
      const element = result.items[0];
      const usrName = `<br>NickName: ${element.userName}`;
      const rnk = `<br>Rank: ${element.rank}`;
      const eloo = `<br>Elo: ${element.elo}`;
      const winrt = `<br>Win rate: ${element.winPercent}%`;
      console.log(usrName);
      console.log(rnk);
      console.log(eloo);
      console.log(winrt);
      found = true;
```

I used **node file.js > file.html** in terminal to do it but I want it to happen automatically every x amount of seconds. Is there any way to do it? I also want to overwrite the last output file.

Comment: you can use something like
   ``const interval = setInterval(function () {
    // Your code goes here
}, 5000);``
change the 5000 to X seconds as you want.

Comment: I'd like to export the console log to a .html file with each loop, that's what I'd like to know how to do @MuhammadAdnan .

Comment: The above example will execute the code after X seconds. And inside the Loop, you'll still have the same behavior, the only concern here is to output to an HTML file.
When your code is running in a loop then using ``node file.js > file.html`` will write the output of your console to the HTML file.
Now if you want to clear the contents of your file then you are probably looking for the fs module. In each iteration of the loop, you can clear the contents of the file or delete the old one and create a new file to save the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just mean print it to the html page that you are looking at?

You can just put a div on the page where you are running this `<div id="output"></div>"`

and then

```
setInverval(function() {
  ...
  const usrName = `<br>NickName: ${element.userName}`;
  const rnk = `<br>Rank: ${element.rank}`;
  const eloo = `<br>Elo: ${element.elo}`;
  const winrt = `<br>Win rate: ${element.winPercent}%`;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = usrName + rnk + eloo + winrt;
}, 5000);
```

but if you are planning on running a node script that outputs to a file, then you have to set a timeout, replace the last line inside the interval function with:

```
require('fs').writeFile(
  __dirname + "/file.html",
  usrName + rnk + eloo + winrt,
  'utf-8',
);
```

and that will delete the file every 5 seconds

... or.. if you don't want to handle writing the file in node, I just figured out from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10650 that you could go....

```
watch -n5 "node file.js > file.html "
```

It's already installed on my system, but it might not be installed on yours I guess

Comment: Awesome! thank you for your help!